# Mockito doesn't mocking with @PreAuthorize and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, mockito

I have a quite problem with Spring Security (using Spring Boot 1.3.1.RELEASE) and Mockito.

When I use `@PreAuthorize` on method `doIt()` on SampleService class, Mockito doesn't mocking method `getValue()` (declared on SampleDao class) inside SampleService during test `doItTest()`.

The result is: `java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<false> but was:<true>`

Its occur because the instruction

```
Mockito.when(dao.getValue()).thenReturn(ctrl);
```

doesn't work when I use @PreAuthorize at method doIt() on SampleService class.

When I remove `@PreAuthorize` from method `doIt()` the test `doItTest()` works fine (Mockito is mocking `getValue()`) .

But when I run the other test `doItDeniedTest()` ,with `@PreAuthorize` on method `doIt()`, its work fine because `@PreAuthorize` throws AccessDeniedException.

How I Can to fix it ?

Thanks for all.

Codes :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Autowired
   private LogoutHandler logoutHandler;

   @Autowired
   private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

   @Autowired
   private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

   @Autowired
   private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/error/**").permitAll()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/adm/**").hasAnyRole(Role.ROOT,Role.ADM)
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home",true)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
            .and()
         .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);

    }
}


@Repository
public class SampleDao implements Dao {

   @Override
   public boolean getValue(){
     return true;
   }

}

@Service
public class SampleService implements Service{

   @Autowired
   private Dao dao;

   @Override
   @PreAuthorize(value="hasRole('USR')")
   public boolean doIt(){
     return dao.getValue();
   }

}
```

My test class is :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {AppApplication.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SampleServiceImplTest {
    @Mock
    private SampleDaoImpl dao;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sampleServiceImpl")
    @InjectMocks
    private SampleService svc;

    @Before
    public void initMocks(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
    }   


    @Test(expected=AccessDeniedException.class)
    @WithMockUser(username="usr",roles={"ROOT"})
    public void doItDeniedTest() {
        svc.doIt();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username="usr",roles={"USR"})
    public void doItTest() {

    Boolean ctrl = Boolean.FALSE;
    Mockito.when(dao.getValue()).thenReturn(ctrl);

    Boolean rt = svc.doIt();
    assertEquals(ctrl,rt);      
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After read the [blog](http://lkrnac.net/blog/2015/12/mock-spring-bean-v2/)  I changed my test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {AppApplication.class,TestConfiguration.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SampleServiceImplTest {

    @Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    protected static class TestConfiguration {
         @Bean
         @Primary
         public SampleDaoImpl gatSampleDaoImpl(){
               return Mockito.mock(SampleDaoImpl.class);
         }
    }

    @Autowired
    private SampleDaoImpl dao;

    @Autowired
    private SampleService svc;

    @Before
    public void initMocks(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
    }   


    @Test(expected=AccessDeniedException.class)
    @WithMockUser(username="usr",roles={"ROOT"})
    public void doItDeniedTest() {
        svc.doIt();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username="usr",roles={"USR"})
    public void doItTest() {

    Boolean ctrl = Boolean.FALSE;
    Mockito.when(dao.getValue()).thenReturn(ctrl);

    Boolean rt = svc.doIt();
    assertEquals(ctrl,rt);      
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are combining integration test with unit test. Don't do that.
You have two options:

1. Don't create Spring context at all, wire the classes explicitly in test and use similar mocking you have. This would be unit test.
2. If you want to mock spring bean in integration test you need to register it into Spring context. I wrote this [blog post on the topic](http://lkrnac.net/blog/2015/12/mock-spring-bean-v2/).

Comment: About combining integration test with unit test , can I separate this ? thanks again.